# Permanent Solution for testing Kerberos testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have Selenium based UI automation using the Selenium WebDriver and we're using Selenium Grid to run them.

The websites under test use Kerberos for authentication. As a result, the automated tests aren't able to load them.

Using a Kerberized FirefoxProfile that trusts the website URIs seems to have only partially solved the problem certificates. We still need a valid ticket to authenticate.

Please help me with the permanent solution. Thank you.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Kerberos, but i think it might be a good attempt if you try to make sure that the nodes have the certificate that the authentication system has.  Have you tried this yet?

Comment: I didn't understand this part "nodes have the certificate that the authentication system has." . I'm not familiar with backend technology of a browser. Please provide me some more information.

Comment: well, as i said i am ignorant of Kerboros, but quickly reading the wiki, it appears that each computer that connects needs some sort of certificate. if you install that certificate on your nodes, then maybe it will work?

Comment: So we need to research about that certificate to install, or can I automate it without installing certificate in selenium?